# получение кода URL

Tags: python, url, requests

Что имею?

После того, как спортсмен принимает запрос на авторизацию, сервер Strava перенаправляет спортсмена на URL-адрес, указанный в приложении (см.рисунок).

Строка запроса URL будет включать код авторизации, который мне нужно получить средствами языка программирования Python.

[image: Собственно само приложение]

[image: Код, который нужно получить]

Вопрос: как подобное можно реализовать в Python?

ссылка на приложение:

https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=51578&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/exchange_token&approval_prompt=force&scope=profile:read_all,activity:read_all

Answer (score 0):

Обычно вид авторизации (с редиректом на несуществующую страницу) сделан для встроенных виджетов, например на gtk отслеживается uri таким образом.

```
import gtk 
import webkit 

view = webkit.WebView() 

sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow() 
sw.add(view) 

win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) 
win.add(sw) 
win.show_all()

def on_navigation_requested(self, view, frame, req, data=None):
        uri = req.get_uri()
        if "code=" in uri:
            print(uri)
        else:
            return False
        return True


view.connect("navigation-requested", on_navigation_requested)
view.open("http://https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?.....")

gtk.main()
```

Но похоже у вас можно указать не только localhost. Тогда нужно запустить вэб сервер (на порту 8081 например) и открыть эту ссылку с браузера указав `redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081`.

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class Redirect(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
   def do_GET(self):
       uri = requestline
       self.send_response(204)
       self.end_headers()

HTTPServer(("", 8081), Redirect).serve_forever()
```

Реализовать можно на любом из многих хттп серверов на питоне.